# Recursive calculations using Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on map reduce program and was thinking about designing computations of the form where `a1, b1` are the values associated with a key

```
  a1/b1, a1+a2/b1+b2, a1+a2+a3/b1+b2+b3 ...
```

So at every stage of reducer I would require the previous values.
How would one design this as a map reduce as at every stage only the values associated with a particular key can be read.

If you feel the question is not clear, can you guide me towards this general question?

More general question: How would one develop a Fibonacci series using recursion in map reduce?

#### EDIT

Can you help me with my modified design

```
 key1, V1,V2,V3
 Key2, V4,V5,V6
```

Mapper output

```
  Key1_X V1
  Key1_Y V2
  Key2_X V4
  Key2_Y V5
```

Reducer output

```
  Key1_X {V1,.....}
  Key1_Y {V2,.....}
```

similarly, now in the next mapper stage. Can I create a list like this:

```
   key1 {V1,....} {V2,....}
   Key2 {V4,....} {V5,....}
```

My reason to do this, is to perform:

```
   Key1 {V1/V2, V1+V6/V2+V7, V1+V6+..../V2+V7+.. , .........}
```

Is it possible to do this? Because the data set is very large, so I think it will be better to use map reduce.

Will changing the design help make it more efficient?

Comment: Are there invisible parentheses surrounding the terms on either side of the division operator?

Comment: Changing the wording of your question doesn't change the underlying problem with the problem you are solving. I still think MR is inefficient for this class of problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem with Fibonacci (and as you indicated in your specific problem too) is the dependence between all terms in the series.
You cannot calculate the later terms without calculating the earlier terms first.

MapReduce is very good IFF you can split your job into independent pieces.

I don't see an easy way to do this.

So any construct "forcing" MapReduce to solve this will break the scalability advantages. Hence a simple highly optimized loop in your favorite programming language will outperform any MapReduce algorithm.

Comment: Doesn't help the original question, but [it is possible to solve for the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence without recursion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html)

Comment: Cool! I didn't know this one. Still, this formula only applies if you need Fibonacci *exactly*.

Comment: Thanks Niels.. appreciate your help

Comment: @NielsBasjes, there is a mathematical method to achieve it for any recurring sequence of order 2. You get the same kind of equations.

Answer (score 0):

Write your mapper/reducer to calculate these three things:

```
the sum of a_i
the sum of b_i
their ratio
```