# Reading a large input files(10gb) through java program

Tags: java, memory-management, file-io, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working with a 2 large input files of the order of 5gb each..
It is the output of Hadoop map reduce, but as i am not able to do dependency calculations in Map reduce, i am switching to an optimized for loop for final calculations( see my previous question on map reduce design [Recursive calculations using Mapreduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712959/recursive-calculations-using-mapreduce)

I would like to have suggestion on reading such huge files in java and doing some basic operations, finally i will be writing out the data which will of the order of around 5gb..

I appreciate your help

Comment: What are the "basic operations" you have to do? Can they be done by reading the files in chunks and processing them in smaller pieces? If so, just just the standard java.io classes (InputStream, OutputStream...) should suffice you. If you have to read the full contents of the file into memory for processing, then you need a lot of memory...

Comment: The two input files contains <key,<List_of_values>>, i need to match the keys and perform continuous average of the values..

Comment: @learner: how many keys, how many values per key (on average)?  what are the keys/values made of?  10 GB where each key has on average one million values would be very different than 10 GB where each key has on average two values.

Comment: @syntaxT3rr0r .. Every key has 100 values.. key is a string and value is a list of integers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach,

Configured the map reduce program to use 16 reducers, so the final output consisted of 16 files(part-00000 to part-00015) of 300+ MB, and the keys were sorted in the same order for both the input files.

Now in every stage i read 2 input files(around 600 MB) and did the processing.. So at every stage i had to hold to 600 MB in memory, which the system could manage pretty well.

The program was pretty quick took around 20mins for the complete processing.

Thanks for all the suggestions!, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

If the files have properties as you described, i.e. 100 integer values per key and are 10GB each, you are talking about a very large number of keys, much more than you can feasibly fit into memory. If you can order files before processing, for example using OS sort utility or a MapReduce job with a single reducer, you can read two files simultaneously, do your processing and output result without keeping too much data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there wouldn't be much to a simple implementation. Just open an [InputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)/[Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) for the file, then, in a loop:

1. Read in one piece of your data
2. Process the piece of data
3. Store the result: in memory if you'll have room for the complete dataset, in a database of some sort if not

If your result set will be too large to keep in memory, a simple way to fix that would be to use an [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/quickstart.html) with local file storage.

Comment: My understanding of the problem that OP described is that processing of one chunk of data from the file is independent of another. On the other hand, records with the same key from file A and file B should be processed together. If files A and B are sorted by key, necessity in storing large intermediate data in memory, in a database or in an intermediary file goes away.

Comment: @olaf, yes records with the same key from file A and file B shd be processed together.. i am currently using the advantage of sorted keys.. will update once i get some results..